# BIG QUERY ERROR: All time series failed to fit, likely because they are all invalid

Tags: google-bigquery, arima

I'm hoping I can find some help with this one. I am getting an error when training an ARIMA-PLUS ML model. The error is "*All time series failed to fit, likely because they are all invalid. Please run auto-arima on each time series to find out the root cause based on the returned error message.*" I have used the same model on other datasets before using similar code (below). But for some reason, this data is presenting an error. I've explored the data in both Sheets and Data Studio and all appears fine. The code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL `project-id.Models.mdl_RevenueForecast`
    OPTIONS (
        MODEL_TYPE='ARIMA_PLUS',
        TIME_SERIES_DATA_COL='Amount',
        TIME_SERIES_TIMESTAMP_COL='Month',
        TIME_SERIES_ID_COL='Customer',
        DATA_FREQUENCY='MONTHLY',
        HOLIDAY_REGION='US'
        --AUTO_ARIMA = TRUE,
        --DATA_FREQUENCY = 'AUTO_FREQUENCY',
        --DECOMPOSE_TIME_SERIES = TRUE

    ) AS 

WITH months AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        LAST_DAY(`Date`) as Month
    FROM `project-id.XT_Sales_Data.xt_Revenue` 
    WHERE `Date` IS NOT NULL 
    ORDER BY Month

),

customers AS
(
     SELECT DISTINCT
        Customer
    FROM `project-id.XT_Sales_Data.xt_Revenue` 
    WHERE `Date` IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY Customer 
),

months_customers AS
(
    SELECT * FROM months, customers
),

rev AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
            Customer,  
            LAST_DAY(`Date`) AS Month,
            SUM(Amount) AS Amount
        FROM `project-id.XT_Sales_Data.xt_Revenue` 
        WHERE `Date` IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY Customer, Month
),

joined AS
(
    SELECT 
        months_customers.Month,
        months_customers.Customer, 
        COALESCE(rev.Amount,0.0) AS Amount 
    FROM months_customers
    LEFT JOIN rev ON
            months_customers.Customer=rev.Customer
        AND months_customers.Month=rev.Month
    ORDER BY months_customers.Month
)

--SELECT * FROM joined

SELECT  
    joined.Customer,  
    --CAST(joined.Month AS timestamp) AS Month,
    joined.Month AS Month,
    joined.Amount
FROM joined
```

Comment: What data type is `Month`? Does it return the same error if you casted it to timestamp? Have you tried running it on a single time series as suggested by the error message? Can you provide a complete sample data? Just so this could be reproduced by the community members.

Comment: I've tried CASTING the Date to a Timestamp and leaving it as a Date and neither works. And yes, I've tried isolating various time series and always get the same error. You can see an encrypted version of the source data here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R2pVsBL3O7djCcT-OjtussrlWJI0QnOp8jmveZmMpfA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @MikeC. It seems your data and query does not match. We can't get the same error using a simplified query. Can you edit your post and data to reproduce the same error.

Comment: @MikeC.I got access denied on your table. We can't copy if the table is not accessible in public.

Comment: @JMGelilio not sure why. I made that DS public to anyone with a Google acct. But at any rate, the source file is accessible and with that you can recreate the problem. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R2pVsBL3O7djCcT-OjtussrlWJI0QnOp8jmveZmMpfA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

With `MONTHLY` if you have two different days in the same month you will get this error. Here's a way to reproduce this error...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL temp.model1
OPTIONS(
  MODEL_TYPE='ARIMA_PLUS',
  TIME_SERIES_DATA_COL='value',
  TIME_SERIES_TIMESTAMP_COL='date',
  HORIZON=3,
  AUTO_ARIMA=TRUE,
  DATA_FREQUENCY='MONTHLY'
)
AS
SELECT * FROM UNNEST([
  STRUCT(DATE('2020-01-01') AS date, 1 AS value),
  STRUCT(DATE('2020-01-02'), 1), --comment out this line to remove the error
  STRUCT(DATE('2020-02-01'), 2),
  STRUCT(DATE('2020-03-01'), 3)
]);
```